# how to send a download-able file to client in django without saving file on the server

Tags: django, file, django-views, download

I'm designing a web site. I have a form with check boxes. I want according to which check box is checked by user, i send a file to user to download it. First i save files on the server, but now i realize that it isn't a good way. because may be a lot of people request for files at the same time, and so a lot of files will be stored on the server. I need a way to send a download-able file to client, without storing on the server. Can you please guide me how it is possible?
(To make it download-able i stored files in media folder and i send data which is url of download-able file to my jquery function in template) Here is my previous code:

```
def dlFunc(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        authObject = socAuthenticationBackend()
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = backupForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid(): 
                //do form processing               
                //receives file from server with web service 
                downloadFileDecoded = base64.b64decode(downloadFile)
                randomNum = random.random()
                strRandomNum = str(randomNum)
                randPart = strRandomNum.split('.')
                try:
                   f = open("media/downloadFiles/backup"+randPart[1]+".tar.gz","w")
                   try:
                       f.write(downloadFileDecoded)
                       data = "/media/downloadFiles/backup"+randPart[1]+".tar.gz"          
                   finally:
                       f.close()
                except IOError:
                     data = "error"
                return HttpResponse(data)
        else:
            form = backupForm()                     
        return render_to_response('backup.html', RequestContext(request, { 'form':form}))       
    else:
        return render_to_response("ajax.html", {}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 0):

If client wants to download, he can only download the file which is living on server. Otherwise you have to be server.

Comment: Thanks... You mean there isn't a way to do this? yes, client wants download the file. you mean it SHOULD be on the server? so, it might cause problem saving a lot of files on the server. you know some times when i want download a file, it doesn't tell me the volume. it seems it's streaming(i don't know what to say) and isn't save on that server, it is just coming to me(client) and so its volume isn't clear. I think there should be a way...

Comment: If any, then you should serve your files in another part of server, this is only my vision. I dont know if it works.. But without server, you cannot serve files, this is for sure

Answer (score 0):

You can use Amazon S3 and have your users upload their file to S3 directly.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/848251/44816

Then you provide the S3 url for downloading. S3 lets you use a cname so the S3 url can even be under your domain (e.g. files.example.com).

Comment: thanks, but in my case, client doesn't want to upload a file. i (from server) want to send file to client and client wants to download.

Comment: That's even simpler. Upload the file to S3 and provide your clients with the link. Regardless how long it takes to download or how many times it is downloaded, you basically only pay for bandwidth.